# Fourier Transform of $|x|^n$

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

I know that Fourier transform of $x^n \Leftrightarrow2\pi i^n \delta^{(n)}(\omega)$ where $n$ is an integer.
I was wondering how is this effect if we want to find Fourier of $|x|^n$? Of course, if $n$ is even nothing changes, what if $n$ is odd. 
I looked at table of transforms, but was not able to find it.

Comment: I'm not sure you should use the delta function here. If I give you a hint: The Fourier transform of $|x|^n$ is $b|\omega|^c$ for some constants $b$ and $c$. But be careful with what is meant by the Fourier transform in this case.

Comment: Curies the person below gave a different answer.

Comment: Actually, the form $b|\omega|^c$ is correct, if you follow the steps I've outlined below. The final result is $$2(-1)^{(n+1)/2}n!|\omega|^{-(n+1)},\quad n \text{ odd}$$

Comment: So, for even $n$ we get delta function and for odd n we do not?

Comment: I'll have to run to a seminar, but I'll try to remember to add another answer on this, form another point of view.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. that would be great

Comment: @Boby: Yes, for even $n$ you get the $n^{th}$ derivative of the Dirac delta function, for odd $n$ you get what I wrote in my previous comment. Try it yourself by following the steps in my answer. It comes from taking the real part (see Eq. (2)), which for even $n$ gives you the delta, and for odd $n$ it gives you the $n^{th}$ derivative of $1/\omega$. The latter term comes from the Fourier transform of the unit step. Again, by doing it yourself it'll become crystal clear.

Comment: ok. Thanks. It came as a surprise I was expecting delta function for odd $n$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Define a function

$$f(x)=x^nu(x)$$

where $u(x)$ is the unit step function, and note that

$$|x|^n=f(x)+f(-x)\tag{1}$$

From (1), you get the Fourier transform pair

$$|x|^n\Longleftrightarrow F(\omega)+F(-\omega)=2\text{Re}\{F(\omega)\}\tag{2}$$

You can compute $F(\omega)$ from

$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}\{x^nu(x)\}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathcal{F}\{x^n\}*\mathcal{F}\{u(x)\}\tag{3}$$

where $*$ denotes convolution.
The only thing you need to evaluate (3) is $\mathcal{F}\{u(x)\}$, which you can find in almost all Fourier transform tables.