# Fourier transform of sum to the power n

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, vector-analysis, signal-processing

I know that if $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform then $\mathcal{F}\Big\{f(x-x_0)\Big\}=\exp{\{2ix_0\zeta}\}\mathcal{F}\Big\{f\Big\}(\zeta)$. I am so confused, is there any relation from this statement to derive $\mathcal{F}\Bigg\{\Big(f(x-x_0)+f(x-x_1)\Big)^{n}\Bigg\}$? where $n$ is an even integer. I tried to derive this from a previous asked question: [Fourier Transform of $|x|^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103344/fourier-transform-of-xn) without any success.

Comment: Knowing also that $\mathcal{F}\{f^n\}=\mathcal{F}\{f\}\circ \mathcal{F}\{f\}\circ \mathcal{F}\{f\} \circ \mathcal{F}\{f\} \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ \mathcal{F}\{f\} $ where $\circ$ is a convolution. This will be $f$ convolved $f$ $n$ times.

Comment: $|x|^n$ is a (tempered) distribution whose Fourier transform involves $\delta^{(n)}$ the $n$th derivative of the Dirac delta. And as @armando said use that $\mathcal{F}(fg) = \mathcal{F}(f) \ast \mathcal{F}(g)$  where $\ast$ (\ast) is the convolution